# Are there any consquences to killing the innocent?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

There are many innocent civilizians in Deus Ex: Human Revolution. Assuming I don't do so in sight of a police officer, are there any consquences to killing civilizians, or am I free to soak Detroit red with the blood of its people?

Comment: They don't provide XP or loot for the most part though, so only sadists need apply.

Comment: I'd call that masochism too, since you're causing yourself a lot of annoyance and using a lot of time to kill people that are of no threat to you.

Comment: Let's face it. Killing sprees are awesome.

Comment: Nope, it only wastes bullets/battery. Civilians never carry or drop any loot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I have been able to determine there is no downside aside from not getting Ghost or Smooth Operator bonuses.

Comment: And Pacifism achievement.